# Who are the rest of the victims supposed to be?

Tags: analysis, breathe

In *Breathe* Season 2 aka *Breathe: Into the Shadows*, J wanted Avinash to kill 10 people based on the emotions of the ten heads of Ravana, which were:

[image]

- Anger,
- Lust,
- Fear,
- Betrayal,
- Ego,
- Attachment,
- Selfishness,
- Insensitivity,
- Delusion and
- Pride

Avinash/J was successfully able to execute the first three people (Anger, Lust, and Fear) but what about the other seven? Who were supposed to be these people? Avinash/J killed Krishnan Moorthy first in the backstory - was he part of the 10 emotions? Do we have any hints for the supposed seven other victims?